# Is it possible to create, package and successfully submit HTML5 apps to the app store?

Tags: iphone, html, app-store

Hello everyone and thanks for reading...

I'm a Mono / Web developer and was recently talking to an Apple guy regarding development on the iPhone and iPad. Now I know that Objective C / XCode is the heavy hitter for development on these platforms; however, I'm pretty sure he mentioned (and showed me) a HTML5 application he had created that while basic was mildly functional on his iPad.

Skip ahead a couple of weeks and I've been asked to check out the feasibility of taking of chunks of a client's 'pay-per-view' website and creating a offline version that can be purchased via (and presumably distributed by ) the Apple app store. Anyhoo, I've been trying to find 100% confirmation that this is possible and I'm turning to dev boards to see whether I can get a definitive answer to the following...

Can I create a HTML5 application (essentially an offline portion of a client's website) for the iPhone / iPad that can be uploaded and distributed by the Apple app store?

And (assuming the above is OK) are there are restrictions or things I need to be aware of, i.e. it is fairly content rich but will include images and poss a few small videos.

Thanks

SC

Comment: would you please accept an answer if it is sufficient or comment if you have questions?

Comment: A good question. Is using WebView via objective-C the best option still? I think I will skip PhoneGap though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the answer is yes and no ;-)  You cannot distribute web apps via the app store. You have to set up your own infrastructure and server to do so.
However what you can do is the following: write a very simple application consisting of a single browser window (called a WebView in Objective-C) and bundle all the HTML, CSS and JS files with it. Then you can use this browser to browse your local content. With a bit more efford you could also implement updating the content and recaching it on your phone over the web.

So the bottom line is: no pure web app can be distributed via the app store, a web app wrapped in an objective-C application can be done.

Comment: Will Apple definitely allow this sort of thing, ie. not reject it? Sounds sweet if it's true!

Comment: Also is it possible to just have the browser window (WebView) simply point at a URL, rather than bundle the HTML/CSS etc. as part of the App Store App, but host all that stuff yourself? I'm thinking: build an HTML5 web application, optimise it for iPad/iPhones, submit it to the App Store via the WebView trick. Would this be possible?

Comment: It could be possible, what I do not get is why do you want to submit it in the first place if you want to host it yourself and do not want offline access? Then just write a normal web app and implement a login and payment routine yourself. Let them use the normal browser to access it,

Comment: @GorillaPatch Because the App Store is an great centralised distribution mechanism, with excellent discoverability (people love their Apps). The web doesn't really have an equivalent other than buying some Google AdWords, or Tweeting/Facebooking it to death in the hope that it'll spread. Even Google realise this and are building their own Web App Store into their Chrome Browser and Chromium OS. Look at Apple statistics and more people were using Apps on their iPhones in 2009 than browsing the web.

Comment: @Sunday Ironfoot That is true.

Comment: Awesome stuff.  TBH I've been looking at Appcelerator Titanium package that sounds like it is doing the business - although it sounds remarkably like a packaged version of what you've suggested here rather than a direct compilation into native code.

Comment: Yes the Titanium package does the packaging. It has some additional APIs to  mediate between the js and the objective-C world, but it is essentially the same thing.

Comment: @SeanCocteau If this answer works for you, could you please mark my answer with the large green hook. Thanks.

Comment: I'd love to see a link to some sample code demonstrating how to build this sort of hybrid app.  Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Dunno if this helps, but someone on Twiiter sent me this http://www.phonegap.com/

> "PhoneGap is an open source
>   development framework for building
>   cross-platform mobile apps. Build apps
>   in HTML and JavaScript and still take
>   advantage of core features in
>   iPhone/iTouch, iPad, Google Android,
>   Palm, Symbian and Blackberry SDKs."

Comment: Can you please find out if it helps?