# Does Apple allow html/js apps in appstore?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, appstore-approval

Is it considered kosher by Apple to create an app consisting of nothing but a WebView and the appropriate html/js/css files to support it?

I have an app that could be written entirely within a webview and it would be much easier to get from start to finish that way instead of learning the parts of the iOS SDK necessary to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an iphone app developed using html5 be sold through Apple store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913321/can-an-iphone-app-developed-using-html5-be-sold-through-apple-store)

Comment: See also [Is it possible to create, package and successfully submit HTML5 apps to the app store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184527/is-it-possible-to-create-package-and-successfully-submit-html5-apps-to-the-app-s) and [Is it possible to distribute an iPhone Web Application through the App Store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157576/is-it-possible-to-distribute-an-iphone-web-application-through-the-app-store).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with programming as defined in the Help Center.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is acceptable, but I would recommend looking at [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), which is based on a similar concept, but provides JavaScript access to native functionality.